# How do I ensure that project-wide SSH keys will be shared and not blocked in Google Compute Engine?

Tags: r, ssh, google-compute-engine

I am trying to set up my first parallel cloud computation using the `googleComputeEngineR` library in R, following Mark Edmonson's [post](https://cloudyr.github.io/googleComputeEngineR/articles/massive-parallel.html).  I have overcome a lot of hurdles but am stuck at one problem: when I execute the gce_vm_cluster() command, I can initiate new instances in GCE, but cluster testing returns a "permission denied (publickey) error" (see code and error below).

I have generated an SSH key and stored the public key in the project metadata, following these [instructions](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#createsshkeys).  But after doing that, I noticed that the instances are still created by default to block project-level ssh-keys.  After reading some [posts](https://serverfault.com/questions/979828/unable-to-unblock-project-wide-ssh-keys-for-gcp-instances) describing similar problems, I also added a metadata key "block-project-ssh-keys" with a value of "FALSE" using the GCE console, but this did not fix the problem.  The instances still initiate with project-level ssh-keys blocked.

I have seen some posts suggesting a fix using a gcloud command at the terminal *after* the instances are created, but I am hoping there is a different solution here that would allow me to execute gce_vm_cluster() to initiate and connect to the instances without error.

Any help you can offer is greatly appreciated.

Here is the code I have executed (with my credential JSON file saved in the current directory as "gcs-key.json", and the username the same as used in ssh-key):

```
    # Establish default setting
    my_project <- "merging-patent-and-dime-data"
    my_zone <- "us-east4-a"
    my_account_key <- "gcs-key.json"

    # Set system environmental variables
    Sys.setenv(GCE_AUTH_FILE = my_account_key,
               GCE_DEFAULT_PROJECT_ID = my_project,
               GCE_DEFAULT_ZONE = my_zone)

    # Loading the GCE library after setting environmental variables allows for auto-authentication
    library(googleComputeEngineR) 
    library(future)

    my_docker <- gce_tag_container("rocker/r-parallel")
    n_clusters <- 2

    vms <- gce_vm_cluster(template = "r-vm",
                          dynamic_image = my_docker,
                          cluster_size = n_clusters,
                          username = "nick-short",
                          predefined_type = "n1-standard-4") # This last one is the machine type
```

And here is the full system output after executing the vce_gm_cluster() command:

```
    2019-09-25 10:16:33> # Creating cluster with settings: template = r-base, dynamic_image = rocker/r-parallel, username = nick-short, predefined_type = n1-standard-4, wait = FALSE
    2019-09-25 10:16:38> Operation running...
    2019-09-25 10:16:45> Operation complete in 4 secs
    2019-09-25 10:16:48> Operation complete in 6 secs
    2019-09-25 10:16:49> r-cluster-1 VM running
    2019-09-25 10:16:51> r-cluster-2 VM running
    2019-09-25 10:16:59> Public SSH key uploaded to instance
    2019-09-25 10:17:07> Public SSH key uploaded to instance
    2019-09-25 10:17:07> # Testing cluster:
    Warning: Permanently added '35.245.255.120' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
    nickshort@35.245.255.120: Permission denied (publickey).
    Warning: Permanently added '35.186.168.226' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
    nickshort@35.186.168.226: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: Try connecting once through the gcloud SDK to a VM, which should generate the SSH keys and put them in a standard location, that googleComputeEngineR also looks for see here https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance

Comment: That worked in the sense that I was able to connect to the instance using `> gcloud compute ssh r-cluster-1`.  But when I ran `> exit` at the terminal and then tried to execute the R code above (under the assumption that now the ssh-keys are stored in the right place/format in metadata), I got the same error.  Any additional ideas?

Comment: Could you raise an issue on github with the above code when you set `options(googleAuthR.verbose=1)` which will give a lot more logging info - GitHub issue here: https://github.com/cloudyr/googleComputeEngineR/issues/145

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be the SSH keys were created with a passphrase.  Recreating the SSH keys without a passphrase let connections occur.